# How to concat double quotes string inside JSON object

Tags: javascript

#Below shows function with JSON object inside #

```
function xyz(field)
{

let object = {

a : { 

 name : _ABC_. + field 

    }

return object;

}
```

**Output expected **

'"*ABC*"."field"' Where
field is equal to value of
input parameter passed

Comment: Hi nag and welcome to SO. Currently your question is of very low quality. We can help you with any problems you encounter, but we're not supposed to write code for you on demand. Please make your question more detailed and specific. Tell us what doesn't work and what you've tried. Do research on topics related to your question and present what you've found. Now you've done everything you can and we might be able to help. And the best thing is, you'll learn a great deal in the process. Good luck!

Comment: _"Below shows function with JSON object inside"_ No, that's not a valid JSON object. That's a JavaScript object. In JSON the keys are in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear. Assuming for input `XYZ` the output expected is `"ABC"."XYZ"`, this would be the code. Double quotes can be placed in the Template string

```
function xyz(field) {
    let object = {
        a: {
           name: `"ABC"."${field}"`
        }
    };
    return object;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

If you have to work with ES5 and below you could also escape the " with a backslash as follows:

```
function xyz(field) {
    let object = {
        a: {
           name: "\"ABC\"" + ".\"" + field + "\""
        }
    };
    return object;
}
```

Comment: Hi Winston
Actually dot(.) needs to be appended between "ABC" and "field"

Comment: @nag updated it. Mark it as resolved if  the issue is fixed

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
function xyz(field) {
  var object = {
    a: {
      name: {
        ABC: {
          field: field
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return object
}
console.log(xyz("String"))
console.log(xyz("String").a.name.ABC.field)
```

Comment: Expected output: _'"ABC"."field"'_

Comment: Fixed the issue!

Comment: I think the value of `name` should be the string `"ABC"."field"`

Comment: In that case, try `a: {name: "ABC."+field}`. I think OP is trying to say that you get the value using `ABC.field` at the end.

Comment: _"How to concat double quotes string"_ The string should contain double quotes.

Comment: yes the string should concat double quotes

Comment: " string " . " field "

Comment: Why did you replace `let` with `var`?

Comment: Wait, not I'm confused. Could you specify an example input and an example output?